# PHP GDAX-API Delete Request returning error 400 “BadRequest”

Tags: php, curl, http-delete, gdax-api

I'm trying to cancel a limit order but keep getting a status 400 code with the only description "BadRequest". I can place orders and get status, balance, etc. but DELETE doesn't work. Here's a sample of my code:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
  $url = $this->api_url . '/' . TRIM($path, "/"); $tm0 = microtime(true);

  $ch = curl_init(); $this->curl_setopt($ch);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  $timestamp = time(); $signature = $this->signature($path, $data, $timestamp, strtoupper($method));
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
       [
        "CB-ACCESS-SIGN:"      . $signature,
        "CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP:"  . $timestamp,
        "CB-ACCESS-KEY:"      . $this->key,
        "CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE:" . $this->passphrase,
        "Content-Type:"   . 'application/json',
       ]
        );

     switch(strtoupper($method))
     {
         case "POST":
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

             break;
         case "PUT":
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

             break;
         case "DELETE":
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");

             break;
     }

  $res = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch); $ch = null; $this->doQuery($url, microtime(true) - $tm0, $data, $res); //echo "$res\n";

  if ($res)
  {
   return json_decode($res, true);
  }

  return $res;
 public function cancelOrder($order_id)
 {
  return $this->query('DELETE', "/orders/" . TRIM($order_id));
 }
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this httpheader:

```
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36",
```

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: What does adding this header do?